# Why did not delete user in table in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, controller

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and going `delete` users from users table as admin. I have following **UserController** function to delete table records?

```
public function delete($id)
{
    User::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return redirect()
              ->back()
              ->with('info', 'User deleted successfully'); 
}
```

and My users data showing in index blade file with concluding delete buttons like this:

```
<td>
    <a class="button is-outlined" 
      href="{{route('users.index', $user->id.'/delete/')}}" 
      onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')"
     >
        Delete
     </a>
</td>
```

and My delete route is like this,

```
Route::get('users/{users}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@delete',
]);
```

but now when **I click delete button javascript** confirmation is coming through and after accepting it still does not delete the records. URL is change like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/users?16/delete/     //16 is user id
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is your issue `users?16/delete/`.  Notice the `?`

Comment: yes thats My issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `web.php` routes file , you have passed `{users}` , instead pass `{id}`:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@delete',
])->name('user.delete');
```

in your blade view :

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" href="{{route('users.delete',['id' => $user->id])}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>`
```

in your controller :

```
public function delete($id)
{
        User::where('id', $id)->delete();
        // or you can use User::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'User deleted successfully'); 
}
```

Comment: same result here? Please note My routes in delete buttons is it correct My route?

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/delete', [
    'as' => 'users.delete','uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@delete',
]);
```

Change the below line:

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" href="{{route('users.index', $user->id.'/delete/')}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
```

TO

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" href="{{route('users.delete',['id' => $user->id])}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: now got this error msg **Route [users.delete] not defined. (View: C:\Users\Nalaka\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)**

Comment: @Muru Fixed the typo.  Changed `'as' => 'user.delete'` to `'as' => 'users.delete'`. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try destroy method like

```
User::destroy($id)
```

Comment: delete method also work by route as :
Route::delete('users/delete/{users}', '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@delete');

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@delete',
]);
```

then check your database table is the user has been deleted or not.
if not then I think it's CI violation in your DB, just because a user id is foreign key in another table you can't just delete it.

Comment: did this but same results. is my delete buttons route correct?

Comment: Could you provide your DB schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `route.php file` to a much simpler approach that helps understanding:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/delete', 'UserController@delete')
->where(['id', => '[0-9]+'])
->name('user.delete');
```

On the route above you already make sure it only accepts requests where the `id` is a number. Also You name your route for easier code structure, so if you change it later on, you don't have to go on and change it in your forms as well

Then, the route generation at your form, would also change it:

```
href="{{route('user.delete', ['id' => $user->id])}}"
```

And at your Controller would change for

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    //Having a hold on your user model makes it able to also delete any other relationship it might have, if you so wish
    $user->delete();

    return redirect()
              ->back()
              ->with('info', 'User deleted successfully'); 
}
```